# Where is the file if the Filename parameter is NULL in WritePrivateProfileString

Tags: c++, windows, ini

When I use winbase.h and windows.h to read/write .ini file, I found that I can use the function

`bool b = WritePrivateProfileStringA("App","key","test", NULL);`
successfully to save the settings.

But I can not found the file. Where is it?

On the other hand, I can use

```
GetPrivateProfileStringA("App", "key", "default", s, 20,0);
```

to get the setting.

And it did not need administrator privileges to write the file, so I think it should be in a user directory.

Comment: Did you have a look at the documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-writeprivateprofilestringa

Comment: It is in the documentation of [GetProfileString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getprofilestringa), point 6.  AFAIK you need to have an ini file with the same name as your application name in your :user profile appdata.   Side note in C++ use `nullptr` and not NULL.

Comment: I would not recommend using WINAPI calls if you can anyway. And ini files are really kind of still there for backward compatibility and hardly used anymore.  Just read/write to/from a Yaml, JSON or XML file and use that (using a portable C++ library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. It was written to windows registry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\IniFileMapping\win.ini` It has the destination for appname which is case-insensitive, by the way USR means HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

If it has administrator privileges, it was written to C:\Windows\win.ini